# SUMIF rows based on selection on other table

Tags: excel, sumifs, index-match

I have been trying to get a combination of SUMIF/INDEX/MATCH to work but failed due to the probably obscure table format. Unfortunately, I cannot change the format as of now.

Table 1 contains the minutes available per shift calculated from a previous function by month:

| Month | Wk_day_1 | Wk_day_2 | Wk_day_3 | Sat_1 | Sat_2 | Sat_3 | Sun_1 | Sun_2 | Sun_3 | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 23 | 10080 | 10080 | 10080 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2880 | 2880 | 2880 | 24960 |
| Feb 23 | 9600 | 9600 | 9600 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 23040 |
| Mar 23 | 11040 | 11040 | 11040 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 25920 |
| Apr 23 | 9120 | 9120 | 9120 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 2880 | 2880 | 2880 | 23520 |
| May 23 | 10080 | 10080 | 10080 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2880 | 2880 | 2880 | 24960 |
| Jun 23 | 10080 | 10080 | 10080 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 24480 |
| Jul 23 | 5280 | 5280 | 5280 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 7200 | 7200 | 7200 | 20160 |
| Aug 23 | 10560 | 10560 | 10560 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 25440 |
| Sep 23 | 10080 | 10080 | 10080 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 24480 |
| Oct 23 | 10560 | 10560 | 10560 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 25440 |
| Nov 23 | 10080 | 10080 | 10080 | 1920 | 1920 | 1920 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 24480 |
| Dec 23 | 9120 | 9120 | 9120 | 2400 | 2400 | 2400 | 3360 | 3360 | 3360 | 24000 |

Table 2 contains a selection possibility to define which shifts to summarise.

| Shift | Work |
| --- | --- |
| Wk_day_1 | x |
| Wk_day_2 | x |
| Wk_day_3 |  |
| Sat_1 |  |
| Sat_2 | x |
| Sat_3 |  |
| Sun_1 | x |
| Sun_2 |  |
| Sun_3 |  |

To show the intended use, I manually summarised the `Wk_day_1`, `Wk_day_2`, `Sat_2`, and `Sun_1` in the `Sum` column in Table 1.

The intention is to select the shifts, marked by `x` in the `Work` column in Table 2 and summarise row-wise accordingly in the `Sum` column in Table 1. I appreciate the help !

Comment: You sum column already have value. What to do now?

Comment: As I explained, the sum column is currently manually created. I am looking to summarise accordingly to the selections in the second table, e.g. if I select the Wk_day_1, Wk_day_2, and Sat_1 columns, it shall return the relevant sum of those three columns in the sum column in Table 1.

Comment: Okay. Let me clarify one thing. Suppose you select `Sat_2` only then what data will be summarise. What would be your output then and which cell of sum column will show the result?

Comment: If only Sat_2 is selected in Table 2, the last column (Sum) in Table 1 would show only the values of the corresponding column Sat_2 of Table 1, ie. 1920, 1920, 1920, 2400, 1920, 1920, 2400, 1920, 2400, 1920, 1920, 2400. Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `SUMPRODUCT()` try below formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$J$1=TRANSPOSE(IF($B$17:$B$25="x",$A$17:$A$25,0))),B2:J2)
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you very much for your quick help and patience !